# UV intensity behaving oddly with ML8511 UV Sensor

Tags: sensor, soldering, damage, sparkfun, uv

I am using the ML8511 UV sensor: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ml ... -guide/all

The sensor outputs a number that represents UV irradiance (intensity) in mW/(cm squared).

However, whenever I shine a light on the sensor, the number goes down instead of up! And when I cover the sensor with my thumb the number goes down instead of up! This is odd because one would expect the UV intensity to go up when a light si shined on the sensor and down when a thumb is put on top of the sensor.

Why is this odd reverse-behavior occuring?

It is worth noting that I accidentally got a piece of solder on the board which might have something to do with it.

Here are images of the solder on the board:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q99JC.jpg

Is the solder the reason my board is outputting values in reverse?

Can I remove the solder without damaging the board?[image]

Comment: first verify * Load resistance of OUT port is recommended more than 100 k and 1V covered with no UV. Add cap on breadboard for V+  Soldering looks like there is a gap on gnd.

Comment: "And when I cover the sensor with my thumb the number goes down instead of up!" I think this is what you'd expect.

Comment: If the solder doesn't belong there why don't you clean it from the board???

Answer (score 1):

Take a careful look at how you have your UV board plugged into your proto board. Your pictures clearly show it offset by one pin compared to the wired connections.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ultraviolet device data sheet shows that it is temperature-sensitive as well as light-sensitive. As temperature rises, output voltage decreases (but not by much). Certainly your finger could raise temperature above ambient. Try a UV light source that is cool. Direct sunlight (not through a window) should raise voltage.
The solder blob looks like it is attached to one end of the power supply bypass capacitor. It appears not to short it out, and is not likely causing reading error.

Answer (score 0):

The sensor outputs a valtage(sic) that increases with increasing UV intensity:

[image]

The first thing to do is to verify that all the connections on the board are as expected. There are only 4. Make sure that the supply, GND and enable voltages are as-expected, then measure the output voltage (without the output connected to wherever you have it connected now) using a voltmeter. Enable should be +3.3V as should the supply.

Divide and conquer.